# How to run autogen.sh and swig on windows 7(SphinxPocket)

Tags: java, android, windows, cmd, cmusphinx

I have been trying to build Pocketsphinx for my android application and I have some problems.

**autogen.sh**, What program that would run autogen.sh? When I tried to install it in cmd, it prompt me to choose a program to run autogen.sh. Why is that? [Build Pocketsphinx to Android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) -- **I have run autogen.sh by using mingw, after i run it i "make" but it got a error:**

```
make[3]: *** [pio.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util`
make[2]: *** [All-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase`
make[1]: *** [All-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src`
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

is this okay? if not how do I solve this?

**swig**, I have tried the instructions [Here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Windows.html) in CMD but when I run swig it says **"Must specify an input file. Use -help for available options."** How will I know if Swig is installed or not?

I am using **MINWG** to work with this sphinxpocket but I still do not know how to work with swig.

I am using Windows 7 Home Basic 64-bit. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install MSYS or CYGWIN,both of them can execute autogen.sh