# Building Pocketsphinx On Android on Windows

Tags: android, mingw, cmusphinx

I have been following this [Building Pocketsphinx on android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) for days now and I am very confused what to do now. I will be telling what I have done step by step so you will know what I have done wrong.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

First of all I have downloaded [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cmusphinx/trunk/pocketsphinx/?view=tar) and [Sphinxbase](http://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cmusphinx/trunk/sphinxbase/?view=tar) and I have unpack it in `C:\Sphinx`. Then I have downloaded **mingw** from [MINGW DOWNLOAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/) only that. after I downloaded this stuffs, I started the mingw.exe and as a amateur I am, I tried `sudo -i` only and that did not do anything so I gone to the next instructions installing **swig**.

I tried typing `apt-get install swig` and `yum install swig` as the same as last time it did not work. Then I have tried `mingw-get install swig` and the result is `mingw-get.exe: *** ERROR *** swig: unknown package`. So with that I tried again the next intructions installation of sphinxbase.

In installing sphinxbase, I have gone to sphinxbase directory - `C:\Sphinx\sphinxbase` and I typed `./autogen.sh`. So with that it compiled without problems and I typed `./configure` It compiled good as well. the next is `make` this is where I got a problem, it compiled but it got errors. the error is:

```
make[3]: *** [pio.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util`
make[2]: *** [All-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase`
make[1]: *** [All-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src`
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

this is the problem I got until now. Then I have tried downloading `pio.lo` from [pio.lo download](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/listen/weichen/sphinx/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/util/). So it fix the error but another error appeared. Second Error:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [sphinx_fe.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src/sphinx_fe`
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/sphinx/sphinxbase/src`
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

This is where I got stuck. I have tried copying `sphinx_fe` from `sphinxbase-0.7-win32.zip` after doing that nothing happens. The compilation would only delete the `sphinx_fe.exe`.

My question is **What Should I do now?**

If it is not clear feel free to comment and ask. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why did you create 3 questions about the same subject? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676057/how-to-run-autogen-sh-and-swig-on-windows-7sphinxpocket, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625926/working-with-cmusphinx-for-android-using-eclipse-ide-with-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW is not supported for now, try to use Cygwin instead.

Actually you don't need to run autogen.sh and make, it's enough to unpack sources

sudo, yum and other commands are Unix only commands, you need to search for their analog on windows.

For more information about SWIG on windows see

http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Android.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. to Unpack Sources by `./config`,`make`,`make install`? using cygwin? I am having a hard time with this stuff.